# How to bring circles to a vertical line in CSS for vertical timeline?

Tags: html, css

```css
.timeline-main-container {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.xyz::before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 10px;
  width: 10px;
  background-color: blue;

}

.xyz {
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <div class="timeline-main-container">
    <div class="timeline-first-container xyz">
      <h1>Master in Computer Engineering</h1>
      <p>Harvard University</p>
      <time>2015-2017</time>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-second-container xyz">
      <h1>Bachelor in Computer Engineering</h1>
      <p>University of California</p>
      <time>2014-2015</time>
    </div>
    <div class="timeline-third-container xyz">
      <h1>Computer Science</h1>
      <p>International University</p>
      <time>2013-2014</time>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I want the below timeline.

[image: this timeline]

I've so far built this.
[image]

Now, I want circles to be on that line. I've indeed added the code for it there in

```
.xyz::before
```

but it's not working. Please help me understand and fix the issue. Why is the circle not appearing? I've set border-radius 50% and background-color to blue, so I expect a blue circle to appear in front of each timeline text around that vertical line. It's not yet positioned though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to position them properly. Changes are documented in CSS.

```css
.timeline-main-container {
  border-left: 5px solid red;
  margin-left: 50px;
}

.xyz::before {
  content: "";
  border-radius: 50%;
  height: 20px; /* Changed */
  width: 20px; /* Changed */
  background-color: blue;
  position: absolute; /* Added */
  left: -63px; /* Added */
}

.xyz {
  margin-left: 50px;
  position: relative; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<div class="timeline-main-container">
  <div class="timeline-first-container xyz">
    <h1>Master in Computer Engineering</h1>
    <p>Harvard University</p>
    <time>2015-2017</time>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-second-container xyz">
    <h1>Bachelor in Computer Engineering</h1>
    <p>University of California</p>
    <time>2014-2015</time>
  </div>
  <div class="timeline-third-container xyz">
    <h1>Computer Science</h1>
    <p>International University</p>
    <time>2013-2014</time>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware I needed to set position:relative in order for that dot to appear. Learnt a new thing today.

Comment: @kdqdmmg0 Not quite. Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`). The dev tools provide an **Inspector** / **Elements** tab. Inspect your elements. The applied CSS rules will probably reveal that the `width` and `height` properties don’t have any effect because pseudo-elements are `display: inline;` by default. `width` and `height` are ignored for such boxes (`block`, `inline-block`, etc. will work). `position: absolute;` (_not_ `relative`) just has the additional effect of [“blockification”](//www.w3.org/TR/css-display-3/#blockify).